# Can we accumulate in a numpy array using values in a pandas dataframe columns in a vectorized way?

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe, vectorization

Assume that we have the following pandas dataframe:

```
test_df =  pd.DataFrame({'start':[1,2,3,4], 'end':[2,3,4,5] ,'signal':[1,2,3,4]},columns=['start','end','signal'])
```

Can we update a numpy array in a vectorized way?

```
nparray = np.zeros(4)
```

Using the compute method below?

```
def compute(nparray,start,end,signal):
    nparray[start:end] += signal
```

Right now, it gives the following error:

```
    nparray[start:end] += signal
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st Create your range , then make the range become a list , then the problem become a [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) problem

```
df['key']=[list(range(x,y))for x , y in zip(df.start,df.end)]
unnesting(df,['key']).groupby('key').signal.sum()
key
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
Name: signal, dtype: int64

unnesting(df, ['key']).groupby('key').signal.sum().values
array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Do you mean this function? How does it work?    
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx=df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x:np.concatenate(df[x].values)} )for x in explode],axis=1)
    df1.index=idx
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode,1),how='left')

Comment: @burcak yes : -) that is the function

Comment: Assume that `test_df =  pd.DataFrame({'start':[5,10], 'end':[7,20] ,'signal':[1,2]},columns=['start','end','signal'])`
Can we get a numpy array of  `[1 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]` instead of `[1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]`

Comment: Also, I have one more question, in this unnesting function is efficient for very big dataframes `def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx=df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x:np.concatenate(df[x].values)} )for x in explode],axis=1)
    df1.index=idx
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode,1),how='left')
`

Comment: @burcak I think it can do with big data frame . But I am not sure about your additional case

Comment: Assume  that we have the following dataframe `test_df =  pd.DataFrame({'start':[5,7,15], 'end':[10,12,20] ,'signal':[1,2,3]},columns=['start','end','signal'])
` I want to come up with an numpy array with `[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 3 
3 3 2 2 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3]`  Is that possible?

Comment: @burcak `unnesting(df,['key']).groupby('key').signal.sum().reindex(list(range(max(df.end)))).fillna(0)
`